# How do I get the rating summary in new products section on my homepage?

Tags: magento, rating, product

On my homepage I have “New products” section. I created it with the following code:

```
<block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage2" template="catalog/product/new.phtml">
<action method="setColumnCount"><columns>3</columns></action>
<action method="setProductsCount"><count>3</count></action>
</block>
```

That works fine, but I want also show the rating summary (stars and amount of reviews) om my homepage:

```
<?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
<div class="ratingsum">
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
</div>
```

The code above gives nothing back. It seems that there are no reviews, but I definitely know that there are reviews!

The problem seems the block type, for new products: `catalog/product_new` and for bestsellers `bestsellers/list`, is that possible?

I have also a “best sellers” section on my homepage. There is getting the rating summary no problem.

Also:

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

Doesn't work in my `new.phtml`. It returns no collection/products.

Answer (score 3):

Below is the code to retrieve product rating summary.

```
$storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
     $summaryData = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')
       ->setStoreId($storeId)
       ->load('product_id');
       if($summaryData->getRatingSummary()){
       ?>
       <div class="rating-box" style="float:left;">
            <div class="rating" style="width: <?php echo $summaryData->getRatingSummary().'%'; ?>"></div>
       </div>
       <?php 
       }
```

Just be sure to pass it the right product id number.